# Flutter - try and catch dont't handle firebase_auth errors

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a problem handling firebase_auth errors, every way when I try signIn, I get some errors,
although I have used try and catch.
Earlier I have turned off the uncaught exceptions option in vsc but I would like to also get the error message from catch

[sample errors message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZzOX.png)

```
Future<Either<LoginFailure, LoginSucces>> signInWithEmail(
    {String email, String password}) async {
  try {
    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    return Left(LoginFailure(errorMessage: '${e.toString()}'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your log, you see the type of the uncaught exception is `PlatformException`, but it is not the type of the original exception throwed by `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`; it is instead used by the flutter framework, when it intercept the exception<sup>1</sup>, to wrap it. So if you want to catch only the exceptions thrown by `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`, check their exact type first, consulting the doc (if it explicit) or with a try/catch without `on` clause, like the following:

```dart
try {
   await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
} catch (e, stack) {
   print("Catched exception: $e");
   //if the exception log not shows the type (it is rare), you can log the exact type with:
   print(e.runtimeType);
}
```

When you know the correct type of the exceptions that you want to catch, then you use the `on` clause:

```dart
try {
   await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
} on FirebaseError catch (e, stack) {
   print(e);
   //exceptions with a type other than FirebaseError are not caught here
}
```

Note **`FirebaseError`** is the type thrown using my package, `firebase` (others exist too, like `firebase_auth`); if you use a different package, check for yourself which exceptions you need to catch.

<sup>1</sup> Flutter has its own mechanism for catching exceptions, which are therefore not really 'uncaught'; see for example this [doc on error in flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors))

Answer (score 0):

This code  only catch PlatformException as written.

```
  try {
    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    return Left(LoginFailure(errorMessage: '${e.toString()}'));
  }
```

you can catch all exception like this.

```
  try {
    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  } catch (e) {
    return Left(LoginFailure(errorMessage: '${e.toString()}'));
  }
```

also you can do this

```
  try {
    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    return Left(LoginFailure(errorMessage: '${e.toString()}'));
  } catch(e) {
    // All other than Platform exception will drop here 
    print(e);
  }
```

Comment: I have also tried that solution but It didn't work :/